# jQuery - jMask money issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I trying to use JMask for money mask, its work good, but when i click on other input, my field money that was for example "1.234,56" became "123.456" how can i fix it?

My field: 
[image]

After after put value on other field

[image]

Automatically my comma broken

My code:

```
<label>Custo: </label>
<input type="text" name="" v-model="vehicle.cost" class="form-control money" placeholder="Custo"><br>
```

[Documentation](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: can you take a look to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vke9ubwh/) and let me know if it doesn't work?

Comment: In jsfiddle plataform its work, just not working on my application :/

Comment: I assume it can be related to vuejs code. May be it possible?

Comment: Yes, im using vue.js but others masks its working good, just money mask that is broken

Comment: well does it support that localization?

Comment: sorry, what its means?